# Find the average of a list of numbers in O(1) notation - constant time

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-c++, numbers, average

Here's the thing, I have a task to make an array with some numbers, after that the array can accept any other numbers of the the same type inside on any position. When I get the final array (with the added numbers) I need to find the average of the numbers inside with a constant O(1) time. How do I do that?!
Here's what I have as an example

Elements: 5 12 7 9 31
Average: 12.8

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is provably impossible. Unless of course you consider only the time for retrieving an already calculated value which is amended on every change to the values.

Comment: So you need to accumulate the data as elements are added, making the addition (or removal) of an element more complex.  There's an O(N) cost during the addition of elements; there's an O(1) cost when you need the average.  You can't avoid the O(N) cost somewhere along the line (but you were incurring O(N) cost as you add elements anyway).

Comment: You question is unclear. If you are trying to find the average of an arbitrary list of `n` numbers, this will obviously take `O(n)` time because you can't know the average until you see all the numbers. If you have an array with known average and length, then updating the average and length for an addition or change in one element is obviously `O(1)`. What are you asking?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler An O(N) cost to add one element isn't necessary. It's possible to have O(1), but as you said, O(N) is still encountered while adding items.

Comment: @KendallFrey: It's an O(1) cost to add 1 element; it's an O(N) cost to add N elements.

Comment: It's not at all impossible or unclear ... the problem statement clearly specifies that the operation of finding the average *after all the elements have been added* must be O(1). This simply requires two elements of additional storage (one for the accumulated sum and the other for the number of elements).

Comment: Now, here's my question: http://whathaveyoutried.com ? That link describes a syndrome clearly exhibited here.

Comment: BTW, this is no more impossible than determining the length of a string in O(1), even though it takes O(n) to enumerate all the characters. There's a simple solution to that problem: store the length of the string with the string. Since C++ employs that solution, str.length() is O(1). Since C does not, strlen(str) is O(n).

Answer (score 17):

If this is an array class you can keep track of the sum of all of the numbers as they are added and updated.  Then when all updates are complete just divide the sum by the number of elements to get the average, and just the calculation of the average will be O(1) since the sum was precomputed.

If this is a raw memory array that you are simply passed, then calculating the average will require summing all of the number, which is an O(N) unless someone is playing a semantics game regarding what an operation is.

Comment: When an array slot is updated, the previous value needs to be subtracted from the sum before the new value is added.